# Incorrect register.phtml template rendering

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-attribute

For some reason, in our deployed environments, instead of the regular **Magento_Customer** register.phtml file, the **Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes** register.phtml file is rendering.

How can I resolve this? I'd either like to force the Custom Attributes version of register.phtml to render locally, or get the normal Customer version to render in my deployed environments.

Please help! This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php magento/bin/magento module:enable Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes Magento_CustomAttributeManagement
```

That will enable the CCA module locally.